# Dirac $\delta\left( \left[\sqrt{p^2+m^2}-\sqrt{k^2+p^2+2\cdot k\cdot p\cos(\theta)}\right]^2 -k^2-m^2 \right)$

Tags: integration, distribution-theory

This question is related to [$f(k) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/321351/0-left-sqrtp2m2-sqrtk2p22-cdot-k-cdot-p-cos-theta-right2-k), but we now we consider $\delta(f(k))$, i.e.

$\delta\left( \left[\sqrt{p^2+m^2}-\sqrt{k^2+p^2+2\cdot k\cdot p\cos(\theta)}\right]^2 -k^2-m^2 \right)$

We found in the link given that the only real solutions of $f(k)=0$ occur when $\cos\theta = -1 $ and $k=p$.

The problem is that to use the composition formula [Dirac Delta Composition with a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function), we must have $f'(k_i) \not=0$ where $k_i$ are the roots of $f(k) = 0$, but this is not so in this case

$f'(k)\vert_{k=p,\cos\theta=-1}=0$,

so how should one go on from here regarding the Dirac-$\delta$?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe one should in this case treat $f$ as a function of several variables instead? The question is then can one take $(k,\theta)?$ as the independent variables or some other $(k,\cos\theta)$ combination and then use the n-dimensional analog of the composition rule? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions Any suggestions?